# Copiar linhas de uma table para outra com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
<html>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="tb1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="a-center" width="60">Codigo</th>
                <th class="a-left">Descrição</th>
                <th class="a-center" width="40">Qtd.<br />Total</th>
                <th class="a-center" width="25">UM</th>
                <th class="a-center" width="25">Enviar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>00001</td>
                <td>Produto 1</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>UN</td> 
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>  
    <br><br>
    <table class="table table-hover" id="tb2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="a-center" width="60">Codigo</th>
                <th class="a-left">Descrição</th>
                <th class="a-center" width="40">Qtd.</th>
                <th class="a-center" width="200">Observação</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table> 
</html>
```

Como faço para copiar os campos (**Codigo**|**Descrição**|**Qtd**) da tabela **tb1** para a tabela **tb2** assim que o checkbox da coluna "Enviar" for marcado na tabela **tb1**? Também preciso que na tabela **tb2** seja gerado um input para preencher uma observação.

Tentei utilizando o seguinte código jQuery, mas ele somente copia os valores e coloca lado a lado:

```
jQuery("#tb1 input:checkbox").click(function(){
 var html = '';
    if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")){
        jQuery(this).parent('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').clone().appendTo("#tb2");
        jQuery(this).parent('td').prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').clone().appendTo("#tb2");
        jQuery(this).parent('td').prev('td').prev('td').clone().appendTo("#tb2");
        //alert(html);
    } else {
      var index = jQuery(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
      var findRow = jQuery("#tb2 tr[data-index='" + index + "']");
      findRow.remove();
    }
});
```

Resumindo o que o código precisa fazer:

1-Clonar as linhas que tiveram o checkbox "Enviar" marcado. 
2-O campo **UM** não deve ser enviado para a **tabela 2**. 
3-Deve ser gerado na **tabela 2**, um input "Observação" para cada linha clonada.
4-Assim que o checkbox for desmarcado na **tabela 1** a linha correspondente na **tabela 2** deve ser removida.

Comment: Eu fiz uma resposta, mas, eu fiquei na duvida em alguns pontos, é para clonar a linha ou remover e adicionar na outra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cada item da linha nesse exemplo deve conter uma identificação, no caso eu coloquei um `data-index` e esse número servirá para incluir e excluir o item da **tabela 2** conforme o `checkbox` está selecionado ou não.

```js
function cloneOrRemove(obj, idx) {

  if (jQuery(obj).prop('checked')) {
    var tr = jQuery("table#tb1 tbody")
      .find('[data-index="' + idx + '"]');
    jQuery("table#tb2 tbody")
      .append(jQuery(tr[0]).clone());

    var tr = jQuery("table#tb2 tbody")
      .find('[data-index="' + idx + '"]');

    var td = '<td><input type="text"></td>';
    jQuery(jQuery(tr[0]).find('td')[3]).remove();
    jQuery(jQuery(tr[0]).find('td')[3]).text('');
    jQuery(jQuery(tr[0]).find('td')[3]).append(td);


  } else {
    var tr = jQuery("table#tb2 tbody")
      .find('[data-index="' + idx + '"]');
    jQuery(tr[0]).remove()
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-hover" id="tb1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="a-center" width="60">Codigo</th>
      <th class="a-left">Descrição</th>
      <th class="a-center" width="40">Qtd.<br />Total</th>
      <th class="a-center" width="25">UM</th>
      <th class="a-center" width="25">Enviar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-index="1">
      <td>00001</td>
      <td>Produto 1</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>UN</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="cloneOrRemove(this,'1')"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-index="2">
      <td>00002</td>
      <td>Produto 2</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>UN</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="cloneOrRemove(this,'2')"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table table-hover" id="tb2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="a-center" width="60">Codigo</th>
      <th class="a-left">Descrição</th>
      <th class="a-center" width="40">Qtd.</th>
      <th class="a-center" width="200">Observação</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Virgilio Novic, se clicarmos inúmeras vezes no botão enviar, ele irá replicar inúmeras vezes o conteúdo selecionado. E como funciona o código?  Para acessos futuros de outros usuários uma explicação cai muito bem.

Comment: @Bsalvo estou aguardando o contato imediato do 3 grau do rapaz que fez a pergunta, a pergunta está vaga, e ainda não finalize a parada toda!

Comment: Opa! Então vamos esperar este contato kkkk, desculpe o comentário prematuro.

Comment: Sem problemas @Bsalvo

Comment: No caso seria apenas pra clonar, só que o que preciso é que seja clonado quando o checkbox da linha seja marcado, e não através de um botão enviar. Outra coisa que esqueci de comentar é que quando o checkbox for desmarcado na **tb1** a linha corresponde na **tb2** tem que ser excluída. Também tem a questão do campo observação que deve ser gerado na tabela **tb2** que no caso será um input.

Comment: Então @MSantos escreve tudo isso na sua pergunta e me avise aqui para que eu possa alterar! Ok!

Comment: Ok, realizei a edição da pergunta.

Comment: @MSantos pronto fiz um exemplo ...

Comment: @virgilio-novic Obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu precisava.